# Button Action for adding items

Tags: android-layout

How to add more items to a Activity layout using a button on the same layout. Items include items like TextViews, EditViews etc which are required to be added to the same layout where the button resides. Please help me in this. Consider me a noob in Android development.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to add items via button you have to add components programatically.

Here's a example of how to add a button programmatically by clicking on a button:

```
final Activity act = this;
//the layout on which you are working
//if using LinearLayout cast it correctly
final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_general);

Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        //set the properties for button
        Button btnTag = new Button(act);
        //if using LinearLayout change to LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        //Set place in layout, make sure you change the values everytime you insert
        //another item otherwise the items will be placed on top of each other
        params.setMargins(200, 40, 100, 50);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(params);
        btnTag.setText("Button");

        //add button to the layout
        layout.addView(btnTag);

    }
});
```

Add this snippet to your `onCreate()` and make the proper name changes and you are good to go.

Hope it helps.